# Can we assign class to shapes in canvas in html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Can we assign a class to shapes in canvas?
I am trying to build a path using lines and want to give a collection of lines a class so as to change their properties specifically.
My code is somewhat like:

```
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(200,450);
  ctx.lineTo(200,400);
  ctx.lineTo(400,400);
  ctx.lineTo(400,450);
  ctx.stroke();
```

I want to assign to a class to all these lines specifically.How is it done?
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is a bitmap board in which you can draw on with no way to track shapes

However...

You can always use this clicking function to interact with your square manually:

```
var canvas = ...
var ctx = ...
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false)
function getPosition(event) {
x = event.x;
y = event.y;
x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
y -= canvas.offsetTop;

// Now put code to describe specifically where to click

if (x < 400 && x > 200 && y < 450 && y > 400) {
// Now if you click on your square, you can write code here to interact
}

}
```

You are also always able to make an array of the squares coordinates and keep track of it that way.

I hope this helped :)